# pyQt 5 editline input size

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qwidget, editline

I'm new to pyQt and couldn't find an answer online.
I have created a form, and in one edit line I want the input box to be bigger and allow longer text.
the only option that worked for me was the following:

```
window.line.setFixedHeight(200)
```

But I'm dealing with 2 issues:

1. the cursor starts from the middle of the box, how can I align it to the upper left side?

[image]

2. there no option to get line down using enter.

I appreciate your help.
Thanks.

Comment: [QPlainTextEdit](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html) or [QTextEdit](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html)

Comment: To amplify @musicamente comment, [QLineEdit](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html) only allows one line of text. If you need multiple lines of text, then a different widget (QTextEdit or QPlainTextEdit) is needed.